# Change the value inside a CLOB column

Tags: sql, oracle

Inside a table "login", there is a CLOB column, where a xml  is written also with the element `UserName`.

```
<login>
<UserName>Test</UserName>
<IpAddress>192.168.1.12</IpAddress>
</login>
```

How to change or delete the `UserName` everytime and entry is added to this table?

Comment: Don't do it in SQL; do it in the app. CLOBs (and LOBs in general) are used to store and retrieve large amount of data, not to edit it inline.

Comment: do you need the above to become this below

<login>
<UserName></UserName>
<IpAddress>192.168.1.12</IpAddress>
</login>

OR this below

<login>
<IpAddress>192.168.1.12</IpAddress>
</login>

OR
Something else ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the `UserName` element then you can use a FLOWR expression inside an `XMLQUERY` statement to update all the existing values in the table:

```sql
UPDATE login
SET value = XMLSERIALIZE(
              CONTENT XMLQUERY(
                'copy $e := /login
                 modify (
                   for $i in $e/UserName
                     return delete node $i
                 )
                 return $e'
                PASSING XMLTYPE(value)
                RETURNING CONTENT
              )
              AS CLOB  
            );
```

If you want to modify all the values being `INSERT`ed then use a trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER remove_username
BEFORE INSERT ON login
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(
           CONTENT XMLQUERY(
             'copy $e := /login
              modify (
                for $i in $e/UserName
                  return delete node $i
              )
              return $e'
             PASSING XMLTYPE(:NEW.value)
             RETURNING CONTENT
           )
           AS CLOB  
         )
  INTO   :NEW.value
  FROM   DUAL;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z9h-ttqM)